# Using ! in arguments to a bash function

Tags: bash

I have a bash function that encapsulates a command to report the results to teamcity (continous integration tests). My problem is that I am unable to negate a the result by prepending a `!`.

```
function run_as_teamcity_test
{
    local name="$1"
    shift
    echo "##teamcity[testStarted name='$name' captureStandardOutput='true']"
    if ! $@; then
        ANY_TEST_FAILURE=true
        FAILED_TESTS="${FAILED_TESTS}    ${name}\n"
        echo "##teamcity[testFailed name='$name']"
        echo -e "\033[31mTests failed: $name\033[0m"
    fi
    echo "##teamcity[testFinished name='$name']"
}
```

This works:

```
> run_as_teamcity_test "Should be true" echo "OK"
##teamcity[testStarted name='Should be true' captureStandardOutput='true']
OK
##teamcity[testFinished name='Should be true']
```

This doesn't work:

```
> run_as_teamcity_test "Should be false" ! echo "Not OK"
##teamcity[testStarted name='Should be false' captureStandardOutput='true']
!: command not found
##teamcity[testFailed name='Should be false']
Tests failed: Should be false
##teamcity[testFinished name='Should be false']
```

Bash is looking for a command `!` instead of using the builtin. Is there a way to get it to use the builtin instead?

Comment: [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) applies; `!` is syntax, not a command or argument, so you cannot simply embed it as part of the expansion of `$@`.

Comment: Why not do a simple string check for `Ok` or `Not Ok`?

Comment: The command `echo "OK"` is a placeholder for running a separate script with additional arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into the issue that `bash` doesn't have first-class functions. The best thing to do is to define a global function and pass the name as an argument.

```
test_goodtest () { echo "OK"; }
test_badtest () { ! echo "NOT OK"; }

run_as_teamcity_test ()
{
    local name=$1
    echo "##teamcity[testStarted name='$name' captureStandardOutput='true']"
    if ! "$name"; then
        ANY_TEST_FAILURE=true
        FAILED_TESTS="${FAILED_TESTS}    ${name}\n"
        echo "##teamcity[testFailed name='$name']"
        echo -e "\033[31mTests failed: $name\033[0m"
    fi
    echo "##teamcity[testFinished name='$name']"
}

run_as_teamcity_test test_goodteset
run_as_teamcity_test test_badtest
```

I'm taking the view that the name of the function can double as the name of the test, but you can add separate arguments for each to `run_as_teamcity_test` if you like.

Comment: I don't see how this is tending to the issue of using `!` in the arguments to `run_as_teamcity_test`.

Comment: It's *avoiding* it, because as syntax, the only way to have it treated as negating the exit status of `echo` is to use `eval`, which I recommend avoiding it at all possible. (That said, I've updated the definitions of the two test functions to reflect the original tests.)

Comment: Note that it is the responsibility of the caller of `run_as_teamcity_test` to pass *only* a single command name as the argument, not a more general shell command line.

Comment: The restriction of not allowing any additional parameters `run_as_teamcity_test` is unreasonable for my use case. It would force me to add an extra level of indirection for two thirds of all existing invocations of `run_as_teamcity_test`. It would be like only allowing a single command name to be passed to `time` or `xargs`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a helper function instead of `!`:

```
function negate
{
    ! "$@"
}
```

And using it like this:

```
> run_as_teamcity_test "Should be false" negate echo "Not OK"
##teamcity[testStarted name='Should be false' captureStandardOutput='true']
Not OK
##teamcity[testFailed name='Should be false']
Tests failed: Should be false
##teamcity[testFinished name='Should be false']
```